# How to add decimals in VBS script

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to make an adding program in VBS, but when I put in 3 and 4.5 for instance my final result is 7, instead of 7.5. How can I get this result. Here is my full program:

```
Dim Input
Input = InputBox("Enter a number") 
Dim Innput
Innput = InputBox("Enter a number")

total = Cint(Input) + Cint(Innput)

msgbox("Total= " & Cint(total))
```

Comment: Can you explain why you use `CInt()`? Have you read this function's documentation? Read it and let it sink in for a few minutes.

Comment: Can you please just tell me? I'm using notepad not a special VBS editor. I'm not a serious coder.

Comment: Notepad has a problem with line endings. If using notepad to write it copy and paste into wordpad to check line breaks. Notepad totally ignores and hides carriage returns but other programs don't. Notepad only looks for line feeds. If coping from browser based documentation such as wen pages and help systems sometimes stray carriage returns get invisibly inserted in notepad.
.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because we're not here to read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fctcwhw9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to you.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is that CInt converts to an Integer... This is a nondecimal point numerical value.

The convertion you want is CDbl()

`CDbl(input) + CDbl(innput)`

Comment: by the way... you can use this as a vbscript editor.
http://www.editplus.com/
OR this
http://www.vbsedit.com/ to get a vbscript editor